# Scala variadic functions and Seq

Tags: scala, data-structures, language-design, variadic-functions

As far as I know, traits like `List` or `Seq` are implemented in the Scala standard library instead of being part of the language itself.

There is one thing that I do not understand, though: one has a syntax for variadic functions that looks like

```
def foo(args: String*) = ...
```

Internally one has access to `args` and it will be a `Seq`.

It is not clear to me whether:

- `Seq` is considered a special data structure enough to appear as part of the language, or
- the `*` notation here is a particular case of a more general syntax that manages to avoid any references to concrete data structures interfaces.

Does anyone know which one is the correct intepretation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is indeed somewhat a 'blur' between language and library. The Scala Language Specification v2.9 states in **§4.6.2 Repeated Parameters**:

> The last value parameter of a parameter section may be suffixed by “*”, e.g. (..., *x:T**). The type of such a repeated parameter inside the method is then the   sequence type `scala.Seq[`*T*`]`.

So when you use repeated arguments, it is assumed that `scala.Seq` is available at runtime (which should be the case, as it is part of the standard library).

Answer (score 2):

I think it is the first one. There are a couple of types that the language demands to exist although they aren't really part of the language. With Seq you found one.