# Scala Currying Functions vs. Basic Functions Explained

Tags: scala

What is the difference between the following two functions definition? Please bear with me if this has been answered before. I don't know what is the first type of function called to search for properly.

```
def f1(a: String, b: T)(c: String, d: String, e: String = "_id"): Unit = ???
```

and

```
def f1(a: String, b: T, c: String, d: String, e: String = "_id"): Unit = ???
```

I know that it is similar to the question mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309501).

- Q1: What is the difference ?
- Q2: What are the advantages of defining currying functions ?

Comment: I'm on mobile and can't write an actual answer, but you can read about partially applied functions and currying: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309501/scala-currying-vs-partially-applied-functions

Comment: Thanks, I'll read it and if there is some specifics that I don't get, I'll update my question or add a comment here.

Comment: Ok, just before closing the question, just so I can be sure of something, this first one is called a currying function?

Comment: to be precise it's a curried function. Currying is a process of changing a multi parameter function into a chain of functions

Comment: Neither of the two are function definitions. Both are method definitions.

Comment: Ok this is the source of my confusion, I can't figure out what is the name of what anymore thanks to Google...

Comment: @eliasah Currying also a benefits from type inference: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32030455/1560062

Comment: @zero323 Thanks ! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A1**:

- The difference is that in the latter you have to provide all the parameters at the same time.

**A2**:

- The big advantage (for me) is the ability to perform [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) of the function.

---

**EDIT Advantages / Disadvantages concept-wise**

`lambda calculus` semplicity:

> In theoretical computer science, currying provides a way to study
>   functions with multiple arguments in very simple theoretical models
>   such as the lambda calculus in which functions only take a single
>   argument.

(nice example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying#Motivation)

Curried functions needs `closure` support:

> Curried functions may be used in any language that supports closures

Uncurried functions for *performance*:

> Uncurried functions are generally preferred for efficiency
>   reasons, since the overhead of partial application and closure
>   creation can then be avoided for most function calls.

Curry–Howard correspondence:

> The existence of currying and uncurrying is equivalent to the logical
>   theorem [image] as tuples (product
>   type) corresponds to conjunction in logic, and function type
>   corresponds to implication.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Concerning advantages conception-wise in software development, besides performing partial functions, why do we need it?

Comment: No problem. I tried to quote few interesting pro/cons editing my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This answer speaks to me more :-)